# How to save image with JRAC

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I tried this https://github.com/trepmag/jrac but I have no idea how to save the image. I tried wrapping a form to it but when posted, nothing is sent. Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: the best idea is probably sending the position & size of the selected area and cut the image using PHP.

Comment: That's what I thought but the thing is how does JRAC send coordinates?

Comment: I took a short look at the source of jrac, it doesn't seem create any input fields which contain data or something like that. You'll probably need to grab these coordinates yourself using their functions and send them to your PHP script.